# Error display while i fire insert query in postgresql , but it can not insert the data in my postgresql. why?

Tags: php, database, postgresql, pgadmin

```
INSERT INTO soma_user_unit_booking ( 
    uid, book_status, book_datetime, dom_id, from_date, to_date, from_time, to_time, event
) VALUES ( 
   '4','1','2016-07-18 18:01:04','27','2016-07-20','2016-07-20','11:00','11:30','Booking'
)
```

- i try to execute insert query in server. and installed postgresql databse in server.
- when I execute this insert query, the data is not inserted in database. and one error display(image attached at last). and data can not insert record in database.
- Another one, when I call static query execute in pgadmin in admin if i check (Paginate results) option so query not run and when uncheck it then it will be run successfully in Postgre database.

can you tell me how can i solve these problem ?

[for reference these image, in which i check and unchecked the paginate option in server database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0inxM.png)

[these error display while executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1Sg7.png)

Comment: when you run this statement in `psql` what output u see?..

Comment: -these error display while executing.                                                                                             sql syntax error:

ERROR: syntax error at or near "INTO"
LINE 1 : SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM (INSERT INTO soma_user_unit_bo..)

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total (INSERT INTO soma_user_unit_booking ( uid, book_status, book_datetime, dom_id, from_date, to_date, from_time
, to_time, event ) VALUES ( '4', '1', '2016-07-18 18:01:04', '27', '2016-07-20', '2016-07-20', '11:00'
, '11:30', 'Booking' )) AS sub

Comment: this is not the statement you show us in your question - please update the question to hold the exact statement you try to run and exact output you get

Comment: ok. edited ! thanks.

Comment: if i  un-check on paginate result option in server then it will be run my insert query. but what is the relation between insert query and paginate result. by default it option is checked

Comment: you want to insert a row. there is no place por paginating. just run `insert` and it

Comment: Please post the error as a text inside the question. The sql error you have linked to does not seem at all related to the query you are executing. Please update the question wtih the relevent part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

try using PDO. here's a simple example:

```
try { $db = new PDO(DB_DRIVER . ":dbname=" . DB_DATABASE . ";host=" . DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO countries(name, capital, language) VALUES (:country, :capital, :language)");

$stmt->bindParam(':country', $country);
$stmt->bindParam(':capital', $capital);
$stmt->bindParam(':language', $language);

if($stmt->execute()) {
  echo '1 row has been inserted';  
}
$db = null;} catch(PDOException $e) {

trigger_error('Error occured while trying to insert into the DB:' . $e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR); }
```

Comment: when i m execute your code , database connection was successfully, but it display blank page and as well as no one error display. please help me guys.

Comment: can you post your updated query statement here please